# Unable to add variable to FastReport Firemonkey frxReport Object

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, fastreport

I am attempting to create a report using the FastReport report component for Firemonkey in Delphi 10.2 Pro Tokyo.  I dropped a frxReport component on to a datamodule,  opened it and created a new report.  When I attempt to create a variable (Data|Variable), I get the following error message:

[image]

I am using FastReports FMX version 1.0.20 which is what came with Delphi.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: To get help with this, you need to give readers sufficient derails of what you are doing that they can reproduce your problem.  So, probably the best thing you could do is to edit your question to include the text version of the DFM of your datamodule.

Comment: @MartynA. There is no project.  I get this anytime by simply dropping a TfrxReport Component on a data module or form, opening it and attempting to add a variable.  I don't have the same problem with the VCL component.  It is possible the issue is with my computer, but I have given all the details I know to give in my post.

Comment: I am using FastReports FMX version 2.5.10 and I dont have that problem with variables.

Comment: @DougRudd.  I am working with Embarcadero to resolve this issue.  So far, nothing they have recommended works.  Just to confirm, are you using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo and is your version of FastReports FMX (2.5.10) the one that came with Delphi or did you purchase it separately?  The tech I am working with says 1.0.20 is the correct one for my installation.  What's strange is that Seattle and Berlin are at 2.2.21.

Answer (score 0):

I have narrowed the problem down to the FastReport FMX installer and Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 and am trying to get Embarcadero to confirm the problem.  I have done this on four different machines and gotten the same result as reported in my original question. Here are the steps to duplicate and test this:

1. Use a machine which has never had any version of Delphi Tokyo
   installed on it.
2. Download and install Delphi 10.2.3 (make sure not to use any of the earlier versions).  You can use the trial version so you don't waste an installation on your license.
3. Download and install FastReports FMX. (https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30729).  BTW, if you have Berlin installed, you will receive a dialog asking whether you want to remove or modify the installation.  If you select remove, you will uninstall FastReport FMX from your Berlin installation.  If you select modify, the installer will attempt to install the FastReport FMX 24 library into Tokyo rather than the 25 library.
4. If you start Delphi at this point and create a Fire Monkey application, you will be unable to find any FastReport components.  You will either have to install the FastReport FMX packages manually or rerun the installation.  The packages are:  dclFMXfrx25.bpl and dclFMXfrxDB25.bpl.  Both are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\FastReports FMX Embarcadero Edition\LibD25.
5. After you have either manually added the packages or rerun the installation, create a new Firemonkey project.
6. Drop a TfrxReport component on the form and open it (double-click the component).
7. Go to Reports|Variables.  At this point, you should get an exception similar to the one in my original post.

Comment: Just learned from Embarcadero there is a new version of FastReports FMX for Delphi Tokyo available through GetIt Package Manager.  It is Fast Report FMX 5.6.17.  I downloaded and installed it.  I can now work with report variables.